# Create a list from structures in Racket

Tags: racket, racket-student-languages

I have the following code:

```
(define-struct p (x z))

(define-struct s (p my-symbol))

(define N01 (make-s (make-p 22 'a) 'symbol))
(define N02 (make-s (make-p 25 'b) 'symbol))
(define N03 (make-s (make-p 23 'c) 'symbol))

(define my-list (list N01 N02 N03))
```

Now I want to have a list that should look like this: `(list 22 25 23)` or `(list 'a 'b 'c)`

I know that when I call this `(p-x (s-p (first my-List)))` I get 22 but how can I do that for the whole numbers or symbols in `my-List`? I think it can be done in a recursive procedure.

**Note:** I need to use the beginner level with list abbreviations

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start by making a function and determine what you need it to do.
You are off to a good start. First use the design recipe to determine what this function will do. It will take in a list of structs and return a list of numbers.
After This we can deduce that we will terminate the loop when we reach an empty list. Using what you made we can create this function.

```
(define (get-p list)
 (cond [(empty? list) empty]
      [else (cons (p-x (s-p (first list))) (get-p (rest list)))]))
```

I encourage you to use this same strategy to make a function that returns a list of Z's from my-List.

Answer (score 0):

I've got good news for you; there's a whole textbook written for you. This is the topic of part two of [How To Design Programs](http://www.ccs.neu.edu/home/matthias/HtDP2e/part_two.html), titled "Arbitrarily Large Data." There's a specific design recipe tailored to writing programs on lists such as the one you describe. Specifically, reading up through section 9.1 should give you enough to get the job done.